# Can sum of two (co)type $p$ subspaces fail to have the same (co)type?

Tags: banach-spaces

[Type and cotype](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/type+%28functional+analysis%29) are very pleasant invariants of Banach spaces. However answer to the following question seems to be missing from the literature.

Let $X$ be a Banach space and suppose that $Y,Z$ are closed subspaces of $X$ both having type (resp. cotype) $p$. Is the same true for $\overline{Y+Z}$?

Since having type/cotype is a local property I guess we can assume wlog that $Y$ and $Z$ are finite dimensional, so that we can get rid of the closure but even then I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: It is rather not true. By Kashin's theorem, you can decompose $\ell_1^{2n}$ into sum of two Hilbertian subspaces, which have type $2$. You can probably form an $\ell_2$-direct sum of these spaces to obtain a counterexample.

Comment: If $X$ is separable and contains a subspace isomorphic to $\ell_2$, you can choose $Y$ and $Z$ to be isomorphic to a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1):

As was indicated by Bill Johnson, one can construct examples of $Y,Z$ such that both $Y$ and $Z$ are isomorphic to a Hilbert space, but $X$ has no nontrivial cotype or type. This can be done on the following lines. Let $X$ be a separable Banach space with no type or cotype, which contains a Hilbert space $Y$ as a subspace (for example $X=\ell_2\oplus c_0$). Let $\{e_i\}$ be an orthonormal basis in $Y$ and $\{x_i\}$ be a dense sequence in the unit sphere of $X$. Let $Z$ be the linear span of the sequence $\{e_i+\frac1{2^{i+1}}x_i\}$. It is standard to check that $Z$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space (see Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri, volume 1, Proposition 1.a.9 if needed). On the other hand, we have $X=\overline{Y+Z}$ since $Y+Z$ contains all $\{x_i\}$. So we constructed a space with no nontrivial type and cotype, which is a closure of the sum of two subspaces isomorphic to a Hilbert space (and thus having type $2$ and cotype $2$)..